# FileContentResult action yielding incomplete file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, download

I've been struggling with and researching this one all day. Fingers crossed that someone here can help me. :)

Preface: I am very, very new to ASP, so I apologize for my ignorance in advance.

Objective: I want to be able to return generated reports in various formats to users via download buttons. The reports are generated fine, and I've got them in string format ready to be shuffled off to populate a file somewhere.

We're using razor MVC for our pages, and thus I've got an ActionLink for the download, like so:

```
@Html.ActionLink("CSV", "export", (controller), new {
                        format = "text/csv",
                        #SNIP VARIOUS USER PARAMETERS#
                    }, null)
```

This posts to our controller:

```
[ActionName("export")]
[HttpGet]
public System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult ExportClubs(string format, #PARAMETERS#)
    {
        string fileName = "export" + ".csv";

        #GENERATE REPORT DATA#

        string content = #REPORT DATA#
        // Tried a few different encodings here.
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);

        // many different header configurations tried here too; this is where the examples
        // tend to vary the most.
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
                "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = format;

        // Tried many different encodings here as well, including text/csv
        System.Web.Mvc.FileContentResult file = new System.Web.Mvc.FileContentResult(bytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain);
        file.FileDownloadName = fileName;
        return file;
    }
```

So, with a click, the file comes over with the correct name and everything! Except its contents looks like this:

```
{"FileContents":"RGlzd...#SNIP VERY LONG STRING#","ContentType":"text/plain","FileDownloadName":"export.csv"}
```

It seems like there's a final step being missed, somewhere, of taking that FileContents and reassembling a file out of it, but I can't for the life of me figure it out. Absolutely no examples I've seen address the matter, so I feel like I must have just missed something silly somewhere.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess , second arguemnt , when you instantiate FileContentResult should be "text/csv" for your case , it is working for me

Answer (score 0):

Your content Type is wrong, the last portion of your code when you instantiate file content result class should be like this:

```
// Tried many different encodings here as well, including text/csv
System.Web.Mvc.FileContentResult file = new System.Web.Mvc.FileContentResult(bytes, "text/csv"); // or what you recieve from arguments
file.FileDownloadName = fileName;
return file;
```

Hope that helps !

Comment: That's what I'd had originally, before I started with mucking every conceivable variable I could think of. Makes no difference, unfortunately.

Comment: you have share content in question , this is actually a stringified json of object FileContentResult , which is correct. , have you decorated action to return as json ? , it looks like there you go wrong